# WooCommerce: parent theme is overriding single product image size

Tags: woocommerce

I'm building a child theme whose parent theme has this code overriding the dashboard WooCommerce single Product image size option:

```
add_image_size( 'tw_shop_single', 360, 999, false );
add_filter('single_product_large_thumbnail_size', 'tw_single_product_large_thumb');
function tw_single_product_large_thumb() {
    return 'tw_shop_single';
}
```

Is there a way to sort of "cancel" this code, or otherwise to override it with my own single product image size in my child theme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your child theme functions.php, try this...

```
function childtheme_remove_filters(){
     remove_filter('single_product_large_thumbnail_size', 'tw_single_product_large_thumb');
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'childtheme_remove_filters' );
```

Comment: edited. I forgot child theme will load it's functions.php first... so in that time, the filter is not yet applied. we can do it in after_setup_theme...